# What is area of grey part?

Tags: geometry, area

Assuming side of square is $1$ and radius of part of bigger circle is also $1$.

So far I got that area of bigger circle is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and I can deduce by calculating diagonal of square, that radius of smaller circle will be less than $\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{2}$.

How to calculate the rest to deduce area of grey part?

[image]

Comment: Have you calculated the radius of the smaller circle?

Comment: @peterwhy nope, but by calculating diagonal of square I know it will be less than $\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{2}$

Comment: Coincidence or not, there is [a recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4460117/89922) about a circle touching two sides of a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is a hint.

If $r$ is the radius of the small circle, and $x$ is the distance along the square's diagonal from the corner to the small circle, then $x = (\sqrt{2} - 1) r$.

Then use the similarity of triangles to show

$$\frac{x}{x+r} = \frac{x+2r}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

From this, conclude that the area of the shaded region is $$\left(1 - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) r^2.$$

Comment: If the side length of the square is $1$, just by looking at the picture, do you think it is reasonable for $x \approx 0.2426$, which would be almost $1/4$ the side of the square?

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $\alpha = (\sqrt{2})^{-1}$ for convenience, and $r$ as the center of the smaller circle. Let us assume the square and thus the radius of the larger circle is $1$. For each point $w$ in the square, let us write $w=(x,y)$, where $x$ is the distance from $w$ to the left edge of the square, and $y$ is the distance from $w$ to the lower edge of the square.

**Then on the one hand, the smaller circle is tangent to the larger circle at the point $p=(1-\alpha, 1-\alpha)$, and thus is centered at $q=(1-\alpha-\alpha r,1-\alpha- \alpha r)$.** [Indeed, let $L$ be the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ i.e., $L=\{(a,a); a \in [0,1]\}$. Then both $p$ and $q$ are on $L$. Furthermore, the distance $d((a,a),b,b))$ between any two points $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$; $b>a$ satisfies
$$d((a,a),(b,b)) = \sqrt{2(b-a)^2}=\frac{(b-a)}{\alpha}.$$ Also, $p=(1-\alpha,1-\alpha)$ and $q=(a,a)$ for some $a<b$. Thus if $d(p,q)$ is $r$, then
$$r=d(p,q) = \frac{(1-\alpha - a)}{\alpha},$$
so it follows that $a$ must be $1-\alpha-\alpha r$.]

**Then on the other hand, the center of the smaller circle is at $(r,r)$.**
This follows because the smaller circle is tangent to both the left and lower edge of the square.

**So putting these together yields the equation**
$$1-\alpha-\alpha r = r.$$

**Then the area of the shaded area is $r^2\left(1-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.**

[Recall $\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.] You can fill in the details.